# margin-top doesn't work after clear: both

Tags: html, css

Hello I am creating a chat UI which looks like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/96a27ffed5203d3b435fe41d8832e1ca.png))</sub>

As you can see, each message is a `li` element  now the avatar and the message div are **floating left**. Now if I don't add `clear: both;` on the `li` element, the elements will go one after each other in one line. So after the clear both, when I do `margin-top`, to create some padding between the message elements, it doesn't do anything unless I add a margin of `500px` or something.

```
<section id="chat-area">
  <section id="users-in-chat">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="images/avatar-big.png"/></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section id="chat-messages">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="images/avatar-big.png" class="message-avatar"/>
        <div class="message"><span>So yeah I am good how are you? I am currently in this shit and i should finish it asap so ill t alk to you laterSo yeah I am good how are you? I am currently in this shit and i should finish it asap so ill t alk to you later</span></div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/avatar-big.png" class="message-avatar"/>
        <div class="message"><span>So yeah I am good how are yoly in this shit and i shou later</span></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

And the css:

```
#chat-messages ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
}

#chat-messages ul li {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#chat-messages ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.message-avatar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

    float: left;
}

.message {

    margin-left: 15px;

    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(144, 195, 245, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;

    float: left;
}
```

What did I do wrong in there?

Comment: Have you tried removing the clear:both and replacing it with width:100%?

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML?

Comment: @AndrewAshton I tried and I still need to have float left because the avatar & messages won't be aligned well, and then If i still have float left I need the clear both because it will go in one line

Comment: Added the real html,  removed Jade one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#chat-messages ul li {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#chat-messages ul li {
clear: both;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```